# Sktexture to NSimage on osx

Tags: macos, sprite-kit

After rendering a scene to a sktexture, I need to get back the image to the cpu space. Looking for solution, I only found solution for iOS but not for cocoa and OS X.
Does it exist a solution on OS X to retrieve image from gpu to cpu using 
Spritekit?
Thanks for help,
Regards